# I am getting this error while debugging

Tags: php, doctrine

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '->'
>   (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\evnxt\evnxt\vendor\evnxt\Admin.php** on line
>   **25**

```
line 24 : $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

line 25 :   $qb->select('f')->from('Fest', 'f')->where('f.dateTime >:date')->setMaxResults(10)->setParameter('date', time());

line 26 : $qb->orderBy('f.dateTime', 'ASC');->setFirstResult($page);

line 27 : $fests = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: In line 26, change `$qb->orderBy('f.dateTime', 'ASC');->setFirstResult($page);` to `$qb->orderBy('f.dateTime', 'ASC')->setFirstResult($page);` (no semicolon after `('f.dateTime', 'ASC')`)

Comment: I don't see a problem on 25, but 26 definitely has a syntax error: `;->` should be `->`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is in line 26.

Please change `$qb->orderBy('f.dateTime', 'ASC');->setFirstResult($page); to $qb->orderBy('f.dateTime', 'ASC')->setFirstResult($page);`

Note:- line 25 seems correct.May be the problem due to line 26 only. please try to do like above and check once. thanks.